# Non nullable types by default in HotChocolate.AspNetCore

Tags: .net-core, hotchocolate

Is there any way to make types (strings or custom class types) non nullable by default and if I need to, then make them nullable using some kind of "NullableType" in attributes or by descriptor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use nullable reference types (`<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` in the csproj) HotChocolate will infer the nullability correctly.

If you would like to add cross cutting concernces to the schema, you may find [TypeIntercetpors](https://chillicream.com/blog/2020/11/18/new-filtering-api/#type-interceptor) useful. With these you can rewrite all field and types depending on you needs